# Mixing Watir::Browser into RSpec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, delegates, rspec, webdriver

In [my previous Watir question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62957/665) I was making a module with `session_FF` accepting a block.
Now I want to make the same but via RSpec. Here is my try:

```
require "rspec"
require "watir"

module Session_FF
  def method_missing m, *args, &block
    @browser.send m, *args, &block
  end
  def element *args
    elements = @browser.elements *args
    case elements.size
    when 1 ; elements.first
    when 0 ; raise "found no nodes using search args: #{args}"
    else   ; raise "found #{es.size} nodes -- use #elements method or improve args"
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Session_FF
  config.before{ @browser ||= Watir::Browser.new :ff}
  config.after{ @browser.quit }
end

describe "it" do
  it "is alive" do
    goto "http://example.com/"
    element(class: "userpanel").click
  end
end
```

I see a problem, that previously I was defining `method_missing` in my own module but now `include` may redefine `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup` or smth's `#method_missing` if it already exists or may appear in RSpec implementation. What is a better way for `method_missing` approach to forward browser interaction methods into `@browser`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have 4 options:

1. Use the current code as-is (and, as you say, risk stepping on an existing `method_missing`).
2. You can use RSpec's [`config.extend`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration#extend-instance_method) to at least limit the inclusion.
3. You can skip `method_missing` in favor of creating a module explicit method declarations for anything you want to forward to `@browser`. This is no doubt the safest, but also the most laborious, solution. Still, I'd consider it
4. You can do something like below, which, admittedly, is somewhat hacky.

```
module Session_FF

  # Alias existing method_missing implementation when being included
  def Session_FF.append_features(target)
    if target.instance_methods.include?(:method_missing)
      target.send(:alias_method, :overriden_method_missing, :method_missing)
    end
    super
  end

  # Define your own method_missing which forwards to @browser
  # or to the previous method_missing (if any)
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    if @browser.respond_to?(name)
      @browser.send(name, *args, &block)
    elsif respond_to?(:overriden_method_missing)
      overriden_method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    end
  end

  def element(*args)
    # ...
  end

end
```

Should work, although if `@browser` also relies on `method_missing` without a reliable `respond_to?`, you might have better luck simply trying to call a method `@browser` and rescue a `NoMethodError`. Not very pretty, though.

On a side-note, I think it's perhaps a little strange that the module is named `_FF` when the `@browser` could be something other than Firefox. `WatirSession` might be  a more inclusive name.